# jQuery not calling the php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

For some reason, jQuery isn't loading my php file. The button is clicked and the page just refreshes. I have verified jQuery is working and the click function is working as well. Once it gets to `$.post` it doesn't seem to call that file and go through the pause and echo the result. The directory is correct for the php file. I am at a loss. Any ideas?

```
// HTML Code    
<input id="doit" class="medium blue button" type="submit" name="doit" value="Sign in">

//jQuery code:
$('#doit').click(function(){
    $('#fullscreen').show();
    $.post('./delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php', function(data){
         $('#fullscreen').hide();
         alert(data);
    })
});

// Php code (test-ajax-code.php)
<?php
    sleep(10);
    echo "Done";
?>
```

Comment: Try `$.post('/delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php', ...` without a dot in the beginning.

Comment: Does it show the `alert(data)`. Try to add `return false;` before the `});` to prevent the form submitting.

Comment: @bazmegakapa - That did it! All documentation I saw said to put that there. Any logical reason removing it fixed the problem?

Comment: @Jason I will add it as an answer then :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa - Great, marked as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the dot from the beginning of the URL.

```
$.post('/delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php', ...
```

I cannot give you a detailed explanation on how a dot in the URL path works exactly due to lack of experience, but I will make this a community wiki in order to let someone explain it.

**EDIT:** I asked a question about this topic, the answers are great: [What does a dot mean in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url/6008906#comment-6943483)

Answer (score 2):

Change your button type.
So, instead of this:

```
<input id="doit" ... type="submit" ... />
```

You should have this:

```
<input id="doit" ... type="button" ... />
```

Why? Cause a submit button will trigger a form submit, which goes to another page. But a button does nothing, well only the things you programmed (with js) to do.

Another solution is to prevent default behaviour of button click in javascript, so you should have:

```
$('#doit').click(function(){
    $('#fullscreen').show();
    $.post('./delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php', function(data){
         $('#fullscreen').hide();
         alert(data);
    });
    return false; //This does the trick!!!
});
```

Why? returning `false` inside a jquery event 'cancels' default behaviour, so form doesn't get submitted

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Changing it to button does keep the page from refreshing but still doesn't load the test-ajax-code.php file. What happens now is it just shows #fullscreen div and hangs up there, never returning the php echo and then hiding #fullscreen.

Comment: So you have _another_ problem else. Does your 'alert' execute?

Comment: No, the alert was not executing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to type button:

```
<input id="doit" class="medium blue button" type="button" name="doit" value="Sign in">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `false` in your submit handler. If you don't, the form will submit as it normally does after your handler returns.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the `;` after to end your `$.post` ;).

Try this, it personnaly works :

```
            $('#doit').click(function(){
                $.post('./delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php', function(data){
                     alert(data);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the name attribute for the submit button and try. I had a similar issue some time back, deleting the name attribute was the trick. (as I submitted the posted data through jQuery, I did not need the name attribute).

I still wonder why it worked back then?