# What does a dot mean in a URL path?

Tags: url, directory, path, relative-path

In a [question regarding a jQuery Ajax problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879663/jquery-not-calling-the-php/5884603#5884603), the asker was trying to use a `.` in the beginning of a relative URL. I advised him to remove it, but have no idea what a dot actually does there.

His relative URL looked like this:

`./delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php`

I tried looking in the RFCs, without success. I know what the dot does in command line (either Linux or Win), it represents the current directory.

I'd like to know: how does this work on the Internet in a URL? Does it have any best-practice uses? Detailed explanations are most welcome.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [path segment `.`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) is typically used at the begin of relative path references and are removed during the [reference resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5), i.e. the process of resolving a relative URI reference to an absolute URI:

> The path segments "`.`" and "`..`", also known as dot-segments, are
> defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They
> are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
> ([Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
> tree of names.  This is similar to their role within some operating
> systems' file directory structures to indicate the current directory
> and parent directory, respectively.  However, unlike in a file
> system, these dot-segments are only interpreted within the URI path
> hierarchy and are removed as part of the resolution process ([Section
> 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2)).

There is [*Remove Dot Segments* algorithms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) that describes how these dot segments are to be interpreted in a certain base path context.

In your case both `./delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php` and `delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php` are equivalent. But there are cases where a relative path can be misinterpreted as an absolute URI, e.g. having a `:` in the first path segment like `search:foo` that is different to `./search:foo` as the former is an absolute URI while the latter is a relative URI path.

Comment: It appears that prepending "." makes browser respect value of the base tag (e.g `<base href="/some/path/">`)

Comment: warning: if your system serves the same content at this url: `http://example.com/folder` and this url: `http://example.com/folder/` then a url on that page of `./page` will go to `http://example.com/page` and `http://example.com/folder/page` respectively.

Comment: @Chintsu That's simply because the dot prefix makes the URL-path _relative_ - as mentioned above. Whereas a URL of the form `/some/path/` is _root-relative_ (incidentally, both respect the base tag - but behaviour is naturally different). `./some/path/` (with dot prefix) and `some/path` (relative path, without `./`) are the same.

Answer (score 7):

A `./` in front of the URL is equivalent to the current path.  So `./delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php` and `delete-misc/text-ajax-code.php` are both relative paths.  In the answer you posted, you asked to remove the dot only, so the path of `/delete-misc/test-ajax-code.php` would translate as an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Edit: one more thing - `.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory.  As phihag comments, these really should be avoided and protected against in code.  Directory traversal can be used for evil.

Comment: I don't think your 3rd example is an absolute path. It is a relative path that is evaluated from the root (starts with `/`).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: It is an absolute path in terms of RFC 3986.

Comment: @kapa: I think the confusion might be between an "absolute URI" and an "absolute path" (or "path-absolute" as defined in RFC 3986). An "absolute-URI" is defined as `scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]`, which this clearly is not.

Answer (score -2):

### Now for a Simpler Explanation...

`.` and `..` are NOT equivalent!

`./` and `../` are NOT equivalent!

`.` and `./` **ARE** equivalent to

**In all cases, `.` and `./` are the same as   or "" or no path so not needed or used on the Web.**

**`.` (dot) is a relic of old UNIX pathing systems** and NOT used on the *World Wide Web* for creating paths! Why? Because the **dot in paths is redundant** and equivalent to "" or `no path` or the current file directory you are in. The same result applies to using `./`. It is the same as "" or `no path`. Both just reference the local directory your file is in ("./webpage.html" = "webpage.html").

**What Path Should I Use?**

1. So NEVER use `.` or `./` as both paths are irrelevant!
2. ALWAYS use `../` which is a RELATIVE PATH and says go up one folder.
3. ALWAYS use `/` which is an ABSOLUTE PATH and says starts from the website root folder.

**Want More Proof?**

Check out the result for these image paths. Assume you are referencing these paths from an HTML web page stored in the root of the web site:

```
SUCCESSFUL PATHS ("../" and "/" paths work well on the Web)
<img src="../images/photo.jpg" />
<img src="/images/photo.jpg" />


REDUNDANT PATHS ("." not needed)
<img src="/images/./photo.jpg" />
...same as...
<img src="/images/photo.jpg" />


<img src="/images./photo.jpg" />
...same as...
<img src="/images/photo.jpg" />


FAILED PATHS ("." in paths that fail on the Web)
<img src="/images/.photo.jpg" />
<img src="./images/photo.jpg" />
```