# Dots in url or path

Tags: apache, path

Consider the path
    ./images/1.png

Here  ./ means current directory..
ie. single dot in path refer to current directory .
similiarlly ../ refer to its parent directory .ie. two dots in path points to one directory back..

So how many back refernces are possible in a path. ie.is '.../' allowed .If so what is its meaning? . and also meaning of '..../'.
?
Also which is correct '..../' or '../../' for the parent directory of the pparent directory of current directory..
Please give me a tutorial on relative paths
Assume that i have access in every directory of the server...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a dot mean in a URL path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path)

Comment: Does anyone know whether these two 'magic' path segments (`'.'` and `'..'`) have names? just calling them 'dot segment' and 'dot dot segment' for now but mmmmm.... Searching for this turns out to be quitte hard :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as "real folders", where `.` is a link to the current folder and `..` to the parent one. There are no others (as long as you don't create them, which is possible, but not really usefull), but there is also no need for others. If you want to go up two directories, just go up two directory: `../..` (and so on).

- `cd myfolder` changes the work directory to the folder "myfolder"
- `cd .` changes the work directory to the folder `.` (which is the current one)
- `cd ..` changes the work directory to the folder `..` (which is the parent one)

At all: Nothing special :) Just folders with curious names

You can even type something like `./././`, which only means the really "useful" expression "the current directory of the current directory of the current directory".

Comment: Is this a question? You _can_ create a folder with the name `...` (`mkdir ...` or e.g. `ln -s ../.. ...`) and then you can use it, but why?

Comment: No, as mention in the answer `../..` refers to the parents parent (and `../../..` refers to the parents parents parent and so on). Also as mentioned: If _you_ create `...` yourself, it can point whereever you like. (--- There is one special case: If you are in root `/` then both `.` and `..` refers to the current directory).

Answer (score 1):

If this is about filesystems then . and .. are defined as directories. At least in linux and dos. You can see them if you run ls -a in any directory. One dot means 'self' and two dots means parent. So to get to the grandparent ../../ is the way to go.

```
:~/.mozilla$ ls -al
drwx------  4  4096 2012-02-18 19:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 39  4096 2012-02-20 16:21 ..
drwx------  2  4096 2012-02-18 19:57 extensions
drwx------  5  4096 2012-02-19 03:31 firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about Apache, and server in general you are talking about Unix filesystem. The simpler I found is 
http://www.december.com/unix/tutor/filesystem.html 
But you will find tons on material.

Keeping it simple:
let's say I'm in a directory. I can find it in my server in two way:

- an absolute path: /home/john/www/this/is/a/very/long/path/
- a relative path : .

I want to link a file in:

```
 /home/john/www/this/is/another/directory/ 
 starting from 
 /home/john/www/this/is/a/very/long/path/
 -----------------------4--3----2-----1
```

you can do

```
     ./../../../../another/directory/
  here/1/ 2 / 3/ 4/
```