# PHP File Manager

Tags: php, filesystems, file-manager, ext4, scandir

I recently started working on a PHP File Manager for my server, as I figured it'd be extremely convient to use, as well as allowing me to brush up on my PHP Skills. Anyways, I have a few questions that I hope can be answered...

- When I list my directorys, there are always a couple of "Dots". For example: ., .., Folder_1, Folder_2, etc... How would I go about removing those "Dots" from my directory list?
- When I list my directorys, my current method has no problem listing folders with underscores, or ones that have no space in the name. However, it cannot handle Folders with space's in their names. Is there a way to get my File Manager to recognize and handle spaces in the names properly?

Here is my current code...

```
<?php
global $dir_path;
if (isset($_GET["directory"])) {
    $dir_path = $_GET["directory"];
    //echo $dir_path;
}
else {
    $dir_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/";
}

$directories = scandir($dir_path);
foreach($directories as $entry) {
    if(is_dir($dir_path . "/" . $entry )) {
        echo "<a href=?directory=" . $dir_path . "" . $entry . "/" . "><li>" . $entry . "</li></a>";
    }
    else {}
}
```

?>

Much thanks for any help,
Brandon

P.S. Are the "Dots" related to my server's ext4 file-system? It's not really significantly pertinent to my problems, I'm just a tad curious.

Comment: `$dir_path = $_GET["directory"];` ... I have to tell you that this is terribly unsecure ... I, so me, not you, can choose the directory!

Comment: And `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` might have the trailing slash .. or not ... server dependant. Short story - you cannot rely on it.

Comment: The only real way to remove the "dots" is to check for them - `if($name == '.' || $name == '..') continue;`.

Comment: @djot Thanks for the advice, I will try to tighten thing's up and work on using more efficient code in the future. Right now I would like to get a simple version working then update it with updated security measures and optimize my code then.

Would you happen to know the answer to my original question(s) though?

Comment: Regarding the spaces you will have to put the whole `href` in quotes. It’s not a problem of your filemanager, but of the html.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton Thank's I was afraid I would have to do that, I was hoping PHP would have a more efficient way of doing handling those pesky "Dots" haha! Much thanks man!

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton, right, always be aware of `.`, `..` and `.htaccess`

Comment: Here are some information about these mysterious dots ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367686/dots-in-url-or-path

Comment: @jotaen Thank you! I'll try fixing and get back to you guys! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a simple version :

```
foreach($directories as $entry) {
    if (is_dir($dir_path . "/" . $entry) && !in_array($entry, array('.','..'))) {
        echo "<a href=?directory=" . $dir_path . "" . $entry . "/" . "><li>" . $entry . "</li></a>";
    }
    else {}
}
```

this checks for `.` / `..` eg current dir and back dir. Regarding the spaces it sounds weird. Is it the link that is not working or is it scandir? If it is the links, replace blanks with %20, eg

```
$href="?directory=" . $dir_path . "" . str_replace(' ','%20',$entry) . "/";
echo "<a href='".$href.'"><li>' . $entry . '</li></a>';
```

more likely I think it is the lack of quotes  `""` around href, eg

```
echo '<a href="?directory="' . $dir_path . $entry . '/' . '"><li>' . $entry . '</li></a>';
```

instead. When you are not adding quoutes, a link with blanks, say "test 123" will be interpreted as `href=test` by the browser, because there is nothing that encapsulates the whole link. It should be `href="test 123"`.