# Nodejs difference between ./folderpath vs ../folderpath

Tags: node.js, filesystems, windows-10, fs

I'm new in nodejs. I try to use some file in my filesystem. I would like to get them through some realtive path. Here is the structure:

```
-app
  -resources
    -tmp
      -file1
      -file2
  -common
    -common.js
  -etc
```

So, I would like to reach the file1 and file2 in my resources/tmp folder from the common.js file in int common folder. I used two relative path methodic:

```
// First , wrong one
var tmpfolder = '../resources/tmp';

// Second, good one
var tmpfolder = './resources/tmp';
```

The file absolute path is something like this:

*C:\Users\xy\Documents\work\nodejs\projects\project_wrapper_folder\project_folder\resources\tmp*

If I log the first relative path I got this result:

*C:\Users\xy\Documents\work\nodejs\projects\project_folder\resources\tmp*

which is wrong, because it does not contains the wrapper folder.

But the second works fine.
Can somebody explain me this behaviour?

---

**UPDATE**

I see the meaning if '../', thanks your explanations!

I have tried @Lissy answer: "So baring that in mind ./ will resolve to the value of your project root..." that sounds great, but the result is not. 
I have this logic in my app:

```
var tmpfolder = require('./otherFolder/orhetFile');
```

where otherFolder is the subfolder of my project_folder. So, when I used this here, I got an error called *Cannot find module* ...

But if I use this './' in fs module, here: /project_folder/otherFolder_2/otherFile_2 like:

```
var path = `./resources/tmp`;
fs.mkdirsSync(path);
```

It works!

these is strange for me. If './' means the current folder, than the example above sould not work (but it's works). 
But if the './' means path of the project root, the example with require should work (but does not work).

Strange for me, is there some meaning of require or fs??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dots in url or path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367686/dots-in-url-or-path)

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code, because different methods of reading files in Node work in slightly different ways?

Answer (score 1):

### In Summary

`./my-file` means look at the root, whereas `../my-file`, means come out of the current directory, and look in the parent folder.

### Explanation of Relative and Absolute Paths in Node.js

The default document root is set with the `NODE_PATH` environment variable (however it would be terrible practice to modify that). So baring that in mind `./` will resolve to the value of your project root.

And so `let tmpfolder = require('./resources/tmp');` would resolve to
`C:\Users\......\project_wrapper_folder\project_folder\resources\tmp` as you have seen

A relative path is denoted by not starting with `./`, so for example `let tmpfolder = require('my-scripts/some-script');` would look in the current directory for another folder called `my-scripts`.

Following on from that `../` is relative to the current directory, but goes out one (to it's parent) and looks from there. You can go out two directories by doing `../../my-dir` and so on (this is not great practice though, as it can get hard to manage if you have `../../../../../../`)

### Better method

You can use the [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) constant in Node to locate the directory name of the current module.
e.g. 
`fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../foo.bar');`

### Useful Links

I think you'll find this article on [Better local require() paths for Node.js](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) very useful.

Also, for a bit of further reading, here is the [official Node.js documentation on paths](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `..` means the previous dir. So you are getting out from **project_wrapper_folder** and then add to the script dir **resources\tmp** and that way the **project_wrapper_folder** is no longer in the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you are inside a folder called `app`.

when you use `../resources/tmp`, it will come out of the `app` folder and will search for `tmp` inside `resources` folder.

when you use `./resources/tmp`, it will look within the `app` folder for `resources` folder and `tmp` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

../ points to the parent directory while ./ points to current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

A dot basically means "go one folder back in the path"

So:
'./' points at the folder you are in.(in your case the folder common/)

'../' points at the folder that contains the folder you are in. (in your case the folder app/)