# What do the dots mean in relative file path?

Tags: php

I am new to programming and learning php on my own. I have two question about the following relative path of a file

```
$fp = fopen ("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/../orders/orders.txt", 'w');
```

My questions about the relative path in the code above are that:

1. What I understand, `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` points to the very root directory of the file structure like htdocs, www or public_html on different servers. Please guide if I am understanding it correctly?
2. What do the two dots mean in the path above?

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a dot mean in a URL path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`..` means the parent directory, so it goes one level up there and into a sibling directory of your document root called `orders`.

Comment: The parent directory of the path at that point, i.e. the directory your document root resides in. Will work wonders if your document root is `D:\` of course, but hey, can't have everything.

Answer (score 9):

.. means "go up one directory".

So, if your DOCUMENT_ROOT was:

```
/usr/docs/document_root
```

your path works out to:

```
/usr/docs/document_root/../orders/orders.txt
```

Since the .. means "go up one", it in fact becomes:

```
/usr/docs/orders/orders.txt
```

You can see how it "erases" the "document_root" part.

Answer (score 4):

`..` refers to the *parent* folder.

SO, if `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` happens to be `/var/www/`, the following would be equivalent:

```
"$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/../orders/orders.txt"
"/var/orders.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to think that the two dots drop you down by one directory level, which usually refers to the parent folder. Imagine `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` is `root`:

```
root/
  index.php   // You are here

orders/
  orders.txt  // You are reading this file
```

Answer (score 0):

A relative path refers to a location that is relative to a current directory. Relative paths make use of two special symbols, a dot (.) and a double-dot (..), which translate into the current directory and the parent directory. **Double dots are used for moving up in the hierarchy.**

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.