# NIO2 Path Symbols Java

Tags: java, nio2

If I created a two paths such as:

```
    Path path3 = Paths.get("E:\\data");
    Path path4 = Paths.get("E:\\user\\home");
```

And then make a new `Path(relativePath)` by using the `relativize()` method on the two paths, creating: `"..\user\home"` does the path symbol(`..`) in this case refer to "data" or does it just indicate a relative path?

```
        Path relativePath = path3.relativize(path4);
        // ..\user\home <- output
```

So my Question is, what does the Path symbol (`..`) represent?

Comment: How exactly have you used `relativize()` on the two paths and created `"..\user\home"`? What't the output if you use `toAbsolutePath().toString()` on the resulting path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the dots mean in relative file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066435/what-do-the-dots-mean-in-relative-file-path)

Comment: The JavaDoc of `Path.relativize(Path other)` ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)) shows an example:  _if this path is "/a/b" and the given path is "/a/x" then the resulting relative path may be "../x"._ The relative path from "a/b" to "/a/x" is to go back to the parent folder ("..") and there to to go into the the target folder "x".

Answer (score 0):

The `relativize` method needs two inputs but doesn't "secretly" encode the base path into it's output, so your `relativePath` has to be applied to another base path to actually access a path on disk.

But you can apply it to a different base path, e.g. if you want to sync two folder structures below two different base paths.

*tl;dr:* it just indicates a relative path.

But take care with your path separator: if you hardcode that into your path strings like in your example, it will fail on other systems. Better split up the individual parts in extra strings like this:

```
Path path4 = Paths.get("E:", "user", "home");
```