# Dot+slash gives warnings in W3C Validator

Tags: xml, url, xhtml, validation, w3c-validation

The W3C validators (http://validator.w3.org/) and (http://validator.w3.org/nu/) both give the warning:

> Bad value ./fü/ for attribute href on XHTML element a: Path component contains a segment /../ not at the beginning of a relative reference, or it contains a /./. These should be removed.

when using urls that start with a `./`

What spec or recommendation says that URLs cannot start with `./` and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path)

Comment: @ScottGrodberg I know how `./` works, that's why I'm asking my question, the validators seem to dislike `./` for some reason.