# Using gridview to display images works locally but not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am attempting to display some images that I have stored in my project folder 
images/bookjackets.

Project Folder Layout:

```
    images/bookjacket/*images.jpg*
    Default.aspx
    Default.aspx.cs
```

Here is the gridview code involved:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCatalog" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Path">
</asp:ImageField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Path") %>'>    
</asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Path") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Path" HeaderText="Path" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

An example of the path I am sending in looks like this:

```
    ~/images/bookjackets/9780316407014.jpg
```

On my server I get the little blue "image" icon.
[Server Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glfSH.png)

On my local host all seems fine.  (Both the imageField and the templateField show  the picture.
[Local view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1StYe.png)

According to the research (having looked all over the web) this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your html in firebug or chrome(developer tool) and try put ./ instead of ~/ in image path location, it also depends on the location of your image folder.

./ represent parent directory where ../ represent parent of parent.

here is a detailed answer: [What does a dot mean in a URL path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path).

Comment: I have the image folder at the same level as my application, and it does work locally which tells me the path is "correct".  I am still baffled by the fact that it runs on my local host but not on the server.  Was wondering if I could place the images folder in App_Data, but I read somewhere that App_Data will not allow the serving of images.

Comment: If you have enough permission for writing file, you can place image folder in app data, however its not recommended.
have you tried using inspect element tool in chrome, if not try different path with prefix as ./, ../, .../. let me also check the link you shared.

Comment: I tried images/ then I tried /images then I tried ./images then I tried ../images.  Unfortunately nothing works. :(

Comment: Actually I think this is a case of using web.config to allow users to access images.  I am searching the boards for an answer there.

Comment: I finally was able to inspect the element and saw that the "url" had ../../ in front of images which indicated that the folder images needed to be in my root folder.  Nice call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change your path ...

```
./images/bookjackets/9780316407014.jpg
```

**OR**

```
../images/bookjackets/9780316407014.jpg
```

**OR**

Direct

```
/images/bookjackets/9780316407014.jpg
```

**OR**

```
~/images/bookjackets/9780316407014.jpg
```

Comment: ../ and ./ did not work as the images folder should be at the same level as Default.aspx.  The direct method and the ~ method works locally, but not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer!

I hope this helps others. You have to place the images folder in the same folder that contains App_Data and App_Code on the production server (Root Level). In addition, you need to add a Web.config file inside the images folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>  
</configuration>
```

You can use this for several websites if you place individual images in a unique sub-folder to images (as I did in \bookjackets).