# PHP form send correctly but I didn't reveive Email

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I am trying to create a PHP contact form by this bootstrap template: 
https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/

This template is working find in my local host, Email correctly send and I received the email.

but when I use their code in my own website, it always said Email correctly send, but I never receive the Email

The following is the code

**HTML:**

```
<!-- contact form begin -->
            <span id="form-title">Let's Get In Touch</span>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="input-style1 form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="input-style1 form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="input-style1 form-control" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Your Phone *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea rows="5" class="form-control input-style2" id="message" placeholder="Your Message *" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <div id="success"></div>
              <button id="sendMessageButton" class="btn btn-xl" type="submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
            <!-- contact form ends -->
```

**contact_me.js**

```
$(function() {

  $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
      // get values from FORM
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var message = $("textarea#message").val();
      var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
      // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
      if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
      }
      $this = $("#sendMessageButton");
      $this.prop("disabled", true); // Disable submit button until AJAX call is complete to prevent duplicate messages
      $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          name: name,
          phone: phone,
          email: email,
          message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          // Success message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
          $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
          $('#success > .alert-success')
            .append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {
          // Fail message
          $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
            .append("</button>");
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
          $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
          //clear all fields
          $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        complete: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    filter: function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
  });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
  });
});

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $('#success').html('');
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;
?>
```

I am wondering do I need any configuration or something else to make mail() function work in my own website

Comment: Avoid using the mail() function it relies on your local MTA, which may not be setup or even installed, also you need to edit php.ini to get it working which is a pain for deployments. Use a lib like PHPmailer or swiftmailer and then use an SMTP service, which could be your ISPs or a 3rd party like mailgun, sendgrid, smtp2go etc, many also offer low volume quotas for free which should help you get going (you could also use gmail), then you should have no issues sending emails, which won't almost certainly land in a spam folder, plus you will have additional debug info in case it's failing.

Comment: Your code is also open to header injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the areas I would look at first:

**Error Handling**

Currently, the script returns `TRUE` after the mail call, regardless of what the call does. The `mail()` method itself will return false if it fails, and [there are ways to check the errors it might be throwing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function/20203870#20203870) when it fails. Your `$.ajax` handler is always going to treat the call as "success" - because the call will always be returning `TRUE`. It may be better to assign the `mail` call to its own variable:

```
$mail_succeeded = mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
return $mail_succeeded;
```

This will let you know if `mail` is actually functioning. The link above has examples of how to use this to also get associated error messages if they exist.

**Relative Path**

Have you double checked that your relative path is structured correctly to be handled as you expect by your web server? This may not be an issue, but the `././mail/contact_me.php` caught my eye.

([From a question regarding relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path))

> The path segments "`.`" and "`..`", also known as dot-segments, are
> defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy. They
> are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
> ([Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
> tree of names. This is similar to their role within some operating
> systems' file directory structures to indicate the current directory
> and parent directory, respectively. However, unlike in a file system,
> these dot-segments are only interpreted within the URI path hierarchy
> and are removed as part of the resolution process ([Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2)).

**Mail Settings on Server**

From the documentation for the theme you're using:

> If you're having trouble with the contact form, make sure to follow
> these steps:
>
> 1. First make sure your website is hosted on a web server with PHP enabled. When the submit button is clicked, the PHP script in
>    contact_me.php runs. If you're trying to use the form locally, the
>    message wont send unless you have a server environment set up on your
>    local machine.
> 2. If you've uploaded your site to a web server and the form still isn't sending, there is probably a permissions/security issue
>    preventing the form from sending email. First make sure that the email
>    address that you're sending mail to is correct. If it's correct, try
>    using an email address with a private domain, rather than something
>    popular like Gmail or Yahoo. A lot of web hosts prevent forms from
>    sending to popular mail servers for spam purposes. If it still isn't
>    working after changing the email address, contact your web host to see
>    if they can figure out what is preventing the form from sending.

Along with this, you will need to make sure that you have your email settings defined and setup properly in your `php.ini` file.
Your host may limit your options in terms of configurability, but [here is a brief tutorial](https://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm) on setting this up.

Check your PHP error log to make sure you're not missing something simple in the setup that is preventing the emails from sending.

Finally, I'd urge you to avoid using PHP's `mail()` method for sending email. There are [several well known exploits](https://blog.ripstech.com/2017/why-mail-is-dangerous-in-php/) that make `mail()` a potentially insecure way to send email. There are other options that can be implemented very easily on your server to avoid the limitations and vulnerabilities of `mail()`.