# "./" in the url. What for?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am currently learning the regular expressions and applications of regex in `.htaccess` file.
And in one of the videos I have seen this kind of code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

So I wondered what the hell `./` is doing before `index.php`?
I tried to type `./` in the URL and it worked:

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter3Test/./index.php/welcome
```

was redirected automatically to

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter3Test/index.php/welcome
```

So my question is where this redirection engine is executed (file where this rule is written httpd or elsewhere) and for what reason could possibly `./` be added to the Pattern *Substitution* in `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sebastian has already pointed out in his answer, the `.` (dot) in a *filesystem path* refers to the current *working* directory (CWD). However, in the context of Apache mod_rewrite, the `./` prefix is arguably an error and should be removed. The "current directory" is determined by the *directory-prefix*<sup>***1**</sup> - which has nothing to do with the dot.

However, unless you are chaining directives together, then `./index.php/$1` is the same as `index.php/$1` and the `./` is going to get resolved away anyway (either by the rewrite engine when the request is mapped to the filesystem, or by the browser in the case of an external redirect).

When the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string is prefixed by `./`, mod_rewrite simply sees it as a "relative" path (any string that does not start with a protocol or slash is considered "relative"). In this case mod_rewrite appends the *directory-prefix* regardless.

For example, given the following directive in the `.htaccess` file located in the document root (eg. `/var/www/example/public_html`)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
> ```

If you requested `/foo` then the above directive rewrites the request to `./index.php/foo`, after which (at the end of this phase of processing) the directory-prefix is added back to become `/var/www/example/public_html/./index.php/foo`.

Apache then resolves away the `./` when the request is mapped to the filesystem, so it becomes `/var/www/example/public_html/index.php/foo`.

So, the `./` prefix on the original *substitution* string serves no purpose here.

> what reason could possibly `./` be added to the Pattern *Substitution* in `RewriteRule`?

To answer your original question.... none.

> I tried to type "./" in url and it worked

The browser actually removes it before making the HTTP request - the `./` part is not sent as part of the HTTP request and never reaches your server.

> were redirected automatically

There's no actual "redirect" here - the browser simply "fixes" (ie. resolves) the URL in the browser address bar.

---

<sup>***1**</sup> The *directory_prefix* is the absolute filesystem path of where the `.htaccess` file is located. However, this can be overridden by setting a *URL-path* with the `RewriteBase` directive. Note that the directory-prefix always *ends in a slash*.

---

See also:

- [What does a dot mean in a URL path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path)

Comment: Thank you for extended information on this topic. Taking into account that I am trying to actually understand the regex and RewriteRule (not just copy paste it from internet as some woodoo magic) your answer is super valid. And you left me no choice except accept it as an answer on forum, for the sake of other users to see it first to have extended info right away. Currently I am reading "Apache mod_rewrite" by Rich Bowen and looking for some particular examples in tutorials.

Comment: You're welcome. "not just copy paste" - that's commendable. Unfortunately, mod_rewrite/Apache directives do get copy/pasted (along with bugs and bad habits) a lot. Question every character and flag - many examples out there aren't necessarily correct/optimal.

Comment: `"Apache mod_rewrite" by Rich Bowen` - When was that written? The version I see is from 2006 - is yours the same?

Answer (score 1):

the ./ characters means "From the current directory" in a lot of systems, and, that is what it means, to look the file that is in the current directory that this file is executed.

You also can say "From one directory above" with two dots instead of one (../)

Comment: Although in the context of Apache mod_rewrite it is rather meaningless (it will get resolved away later when the request is mapped to the filesystem).

Comment: I have totally forgotten about this feature... I feel that I am such a dummy...(( Thanks a lot for answer and clarification comment.

Comment: Sebastian, I am sorry but I had to mark as an answer  the answer from @MrWhite  for sake of other users to see the extended information he has given. But I upvoted your comment and thanked for it. I hope you won't be offended by my choice. I did it more for the community not for the determining better unswer.  Regards.