# Safe use of require() in PHP

Tags: php

What does the period (.) in the following php function mean:

```
require("./folder/file.php");
```

And on the security issue, is using the function in the above way safe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a dot mean in a URL path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008829/what-does-a-dot-mean-in-a-url-path)

Comment: @kmoser Although it's the same exact meaning, it's probably not the best example since `require` only accepts URLs when some magic is involved (and it's a dubious practice from security standpoint).

Comment: I couldn't find a proper question to link, but here's an overview: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Here is a better example: https://superuser.com/questions/37449/what-are-and-in-a-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` (dot) means a relative path, `require("./folder/file.php");` means that you are working in the same folder. There no risk at all, it is just a reference to a file.

`..` (two dots) is one level higher
`../../` (two dots slashes) two levels higher

[further info](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths)